# Rails 3.2.1 login with two possible answers: js or html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a login form that send the login info with Ajax.

If the login is wrong, I send a .js that shows some alert and shakes the form.

If the login is successfull, I simply want to redirect the full page.

The Rails controller expect always a .js call, and actually in both cases I send a .js reply, because the redirect in rails will go into some .js reply that the browser expect.

```
login wrong:
$("#login").effect("shake", { times:2 , distance:10},20);


login successfull:
window.location.replace("<%=root_url(:only_path => false)%>enterprises/");
```

The question is if this is a good approach (personally I don't like it but it works) or are better ways to handle this.

thanks,

Comment: What is your problem with this solution? I think it is a good one.

Comment: Currently I don't have any problem, but I'm asking if it's a better way to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a good solution. Mayby I would fix the url in case of a successful to depend on a helper, instead of a hardcoded path, but it is a minor thing.

Maybe it can be good to have an additional .html view on both actions in case of the user disabled the javascript in the browser.

Comment: I have additional .html views, but this Web is an ERP for in-house project, so we have only specific users with speficic browsers.